# What is the explicit bijection between $\text{Cat} (A \times B, C) \cong \text{Cat} (A, C^B)$?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

From Category Theory by Mac Lane:

> For small categories $A, B, C$ establish a bijection between $\text{Cat} (A \times B, C) \cong \text{Cat} (A, C^B)$.

I'm having trouble coming up with the bijection between these two sets.

I see that it would have to be some function $f : \text{Cat} (A \times B, C) \rightarrow \text{Cat} (A, C^B)$ such that $f :(F:A \times B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (F':A \rightarrow C^B) $ where $F$ and $F'$ are functors, but I can't figure out a way to define $f$ so that there's an appropriate inverse.

Anyone have any ideas as to how to explicitly define the bijection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A,B,C$ are sets, you have a bijection between the sets of functions $C^{A\times B}$ and $(C^B)^A$. Given $F\colon A\times B\to C$ then you may **[curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)** the function of two variables, treating it as a function-valued function of one variable, by temporarily holding the second argument fixed. This (or a generalization of this) is also known as the **[hom-tensor adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction)** in a category theoretic context.

Explicitly, if $F(-,-)$ is a function of two variables, I may (as almost just a matter of notation), elect to fix an $a$ value and hold it constant. I leave the second argument variable. Then $F(a,-)$ may be viewed as a function $B\to C$, which takes $b$ to the value $F(a,b)$. For each $a$ I can do this. For each $a$ I turn $F$ into a function $B\to C$. Thus I have constructed a function $A\to C^B.$ this is called currying $F$. $\text{curry}(F)(a)$ is the map that takes $b$ to $F(a,b).$

So to recap in short, $\text{curry}(F)=f(F)$ is the function taking the value on a function $F\colon A\times B\to C$ of $f(F)(a)(b)=F(a,b)$.

Then the inverse $g\colon (C^B)^A\to C^{A\times B}$ is defined, for $F'\colon A\to C^B$, as $g(F')(a,b)=F'(a)(b).$ This may be called the de-currying of $F'$.

It follows immediately that $f\colon C^{A\times B}\to (C^B)^A$ and $g\colon (C^B)^A \to C^{A\times B}$ are inverse.

For functors of categories it is the same, but the functors act on arrows as well, in the obvious way. One must also verify these maps obey the functor axioms.

Comment: @ziggurism Could you be a little more explicit?  I'm having trouble with the abstraction and I don't see the obvious way that this shows the bijection between the two sets.

Comment: @OliverG I added some more explanation, maybe it’s clearer now?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "is the function taking the value on a function $F : A \times B \rightarrow C $ of $f(F)(a)(b)=F(a,b)$"?  I'm having trouble understanding the wording.

Comment: Every function $ f : X\times Y \to Z$ that takes two arguments can be regarded as a function $\hat f$ that takes a single argument $X$ but has a different codomain, "functions from $Y$ to $Z$". This is true because (a) a function is determined by the values that it takes and (b) $\hat f(x)$ is a function $f_x$ such that $f_x(y)=f(x,y)$ for each $x,y$. This identification seems pretty tautological because principle (a) is quite primitive in your intuition of what a function is.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian hey fosco.

Comment: @OliverG What it means is $f$ eats functions $F\colon A\times B\to C$, and returns functions $A\to C^B$. The value of $f$ on the function $F$ is notated $f(F)$. It's my job to tell you that value. The value of $f(F)$ is a function $A\to C^B$. Therefore to tell you the value of $f(F)$, it is enough to tell you what value $f(F)$ takes at each element $a$. To specify $f(F)(a).$ But $f(F)(a)$ is an element of $C^B.$ A function. It is therefore enough to specify the value at each element $b$. I have to give $f(F)(a)(b).$ And it equals the only thing it _can_ equal, namely $F(a,b).$

Comment: Because $f(F)(a)$ is the version of $F$ which has fixed $a$ and keeps $b$ variable. I also like the way Fosco explained it. Hopefully one of the explanations will help. But please ask if further clarification is necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.  I was having trouble differentiating between the fact that $f,g$ map FUNCTORS to other FUNCTORS, and that the object and arrow functors are changed as well based on the changes to the functors.